# Xamarin Forms Padding in StaticResource

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to build few pages with specific Padding in sytacklayout. I do not want to wrote it in every pages. And its not good design considering if I want to change it in future. Is there a way to define padding in static resource? So that I can define it in one place `App.xml` and use it in other pages.

I have tried

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <x:String x:Key="padding">45, 0, 45, 0</x:String>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
<StackLayout Padding="{StaticResource padding}">
    <Label Text="{StaticResource padding}"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/application/

Comment: Is is possible to use StaticResource. I solved it using style already. But I need to use static resource. Define style for one property doesn't seem good to me. Please advice. And thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As said, you should use `Thickness`. In addition, for setting your resource at the Application level, put it in your `App.xaml` file:

```
<Application ...>
 <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Thickness x:Key="padding">45,0, 45, 0</Thickness>
            // some others resources...
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Then call it from your different pages:

```
<ContentPage>
    <StackLayout Padding="{StaticResource padding}">
        <Label Text="{StaticResource padding}"/>
    </StackLayout>
    ...
```

[link to documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/resource-dictionaries/)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Just use `Thickness` instead of a `string`:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
<ResourceDictionary>
    <Thickness x:Key="padding">45,0</Thickness>
</ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
<StackLayout Padding="{StaticResource padding}">
    <Label Text="{StaticResource padding}"/>
</StackLayout>
```